# ElasticSearch - combining search queries not working

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to have an intersection of 2 queries
I got 3 documents in the index:

```
"_id": "68c220aa-ea51-4f84-b880-29af3302cae9",
"_id": "b6c1c3c5-e959-480f-a145-f5598fafea66",
"_id": "2d30de72-0a2b-465c-8770-970ad9760d47",
```

Query1:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "attributes.asReference": {
                                                "query": "8670ff39-6a0d-4ae8-e217-08d88efd4771"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "attributes.attributeId": {
                                                "query": "f51ca670-4223-4ea2-8007-d111dd38a14f"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }                                   
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [
        {
            "modified": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        },
        {
            "created": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

returns all 3 documents as it should

```
"_id": "68c220aa-ea51-4f84-b880-29af3302cae9",
"_id": "b6c1c3c5-e959-480f-a145-f5598fafea66",
"_id": "2d30de72-0a2b-465c-8770-970ad9760d47",
```

Then I do query2:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "attributes.asShortString": {
                                                "query": "RA-005"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "attributes.attributeId": {
                                                "query": "7ff3dbc1-3586-4475-9162-5430bb06c6d0"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [
        {
            "modified": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        },
        {
            "created": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

returns 1 document:

```
"_id": "b6c1c3c5-e959-480f-a145-f5598fafea66"
```

But when I combine the queries to:

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "attributes.asReference": {
                                                "query": "8670ff39-6a0d-4ae8-e217-08d88efd4771"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "attributes.attributeId": {
                                                "query": "f51ca670-4223-4ea2-8007-d111dd38a14f"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "attributes.asShortString": {
                                                "query": "RA-005"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "attributes.attributeId": {
                                                "query": "7ff3dbc1-3586-4475-9162-5430bb06c6d0"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 10,
    "sort": [
        {
            "modified": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        },
        {
            "created": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Here I do not get any documents

So the subqueries are working but combined it does not work (it produces 0 results)

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the way nested documents and queries work, you need to have two separate `nested` queries in your `bool/must` query, because each will/might match a different nested document of the same parent document:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match_phrase": {
                            "attributes.asReference": {
                              "query": "8670ff39-6a0d-4ae8-e217-08d88efd4771"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match_phrase": {
                            "attributes.attributeId": {
                              "query": "f51ca670-4223-4ea2-8007-d111dd38a14f"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "attributes",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": [
                        {
                          "match_phrase": {
                            "attributes.asShortString": {
                              "query": "RA-005"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        {
                          "match_phrase": {
                            "attributes.attributeId": {
                              "query": "7ff3dbc1-3586-4475-9162-5430bb06c6d0"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [
    {
      "modified": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "created": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```